# Can't pick images with path stored on the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, ckeditor, kcfinder

I have built a system where a user logs in and saves an avatar via CKEditor/KCFinder via textarea. It works as I want it to work. Images are saved in a folder and the path to them on a database. The problem comes when I try to display the images in a table. I keep on getting double html tags and I can't really find a way to escape them so that I get just what I need to display the images.

**Here is the script:** *linklabel is the name of the row where the avatar path is saved*

```
<?php
    require_once "../scripts/conector.php";

    if (!$_GET['pid']) {
    $pageid = '1';
    } else {
        $pageid = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
    }

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($myConnection)); 

    $listadeavatars = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $avatar = "<img src='" . $row["linklabel"] . "' height='160' width='160'/>";

        $listadeavatars .= '<tr>
                                <td>' . $avatar . '</td>
                                <td>' . $pid . '</td>
                            </tr>';
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
?>
```

And here is the HTML output when I inspect the HTML:

```
<img width="160" height="160" src="<img alt="" src="/nysida/admin/kcfinder/upload/images/avatar/avatar.jpg" style="height:160px; width:160px" />">
```

How can I get rid of the double HTML in order to display the images?

**UPDATE:**

If I use simply `$avatar = $row["linklabel"];`, then the result will be the one shown below:
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your second example then, just using '$avatar = $row["linklabel"];' directly? Seems like a valid <img> tag...

Comment: What is wrong is that I do not want to display the HTML, I want to display the image. If I change to '$avatar = $row["linklabel"];' then I get the HTML output that is saved on the database. Please let me know if I am not explaining myself well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You say you don't want the HTML, but <img src="image.jpg"/> IS the HTML needed to display an image... How else would you display an image?

Comment: No prob, I will try again: if I use the method '$avatar = $row["linklabel"];', the output will be the one on the image that I show above (the printed HTML). But what I want is to SEE the image itself and not the printed HTML. So, I want to pick up all the images and show them, not show the actual HTML. Better?

Comment: What do you see when you use '$avatar = html_entity_decode($row["linklabel"])'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `$row["linklabel"]` already contains the whole `<img>` tag, just change

```
$avatar = "<img src='" . $row["linklabel"] . "' height='160' width='160'/>";
```

into

```
$avatar = $row["linklabel"];
```

**UPDATE**

If you're seeing the actual tag in your webpage, you need to also decode the image tag using `html_entity_decode()`, like so:

```
$avatar = html_entity_decode($row["linklabel"]);
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please see it above. Thanks!